# Job error on a multi-chain chainlink node version:1.2.0

Tags: chainlink

I have a chainlink node running on two chains evmChainID=4(rinkeby) and evmChainID=80001(Mumbai-polygon)

I have deployed a TestnetConsumer contract on Mumbai which fetches the latest Ethereum price.

The Jobspec created for the consuming contract is as follows:

```
type = "directrequest"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "Get > Uint256-MUMBAI-POLYGON"
externalJobID = "1d77fe57-fd0c-4ee7-ba6e-e5e40a0e72c4"
maxTaskDuration = "0s"
contractAddress = "0x-my-oracle-contract"
evmChainID = "80001"
minIncomingConfirmations = 0
observationSource = """
    decode_log   [type="ethabidecodelog"
                  abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)"
                  data="$(jobRun.logData)"
                  topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]

    decode_cbor  [type="cborparse" data="$(decode_log.data)"]
    fetch        [type="http" method=GET url="$(decode_cbor.get)"]
    parse        [type="jsonparse" path="$(decode_cbor.path)" data="$(fetch)"]
    multiply     [type="multiply" input="$(parse)" times=100]
    encode_data  [type="ethabiencode" abi="(uint256 value)" data="{ \\"value\\": $(multiply) }"]
    encode_tx    [type="ethabiencode"
                  abi="fulfillOracleRequest(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes32 data)"
                  data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"payment\\": $(decode_log.payment), \\"callbackAddress\\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \\"callbackFunctionId\\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \\"expiration\\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \\"data\\": $(encode_data)}"
                 ]
    submit_tx    [type="ethtx" to="0x-my-oracle-contract" data="$(encode_tx)" evmChainID="80001"]

    decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> parse -> multiply -> encode_data -> encode_tx -> submit_tx
"""
```

The job runs keep getting success and error alternatively. The error happens because the node tries to send the txn using the key bound to evmChainID=4 as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Errored JOB]
Errors:
while creating transaction: cannot send transaction on chain ID 80001; eth key with address 0xED3413f20d7F16B5E8934aFf935FD763a3Bd63Cf is pegged to chain ID 4: task run failed

It seems its an error related to some default config. Please help. Thanks

The expectation is the Job spec written specific for evmChainID=80001 will use the key bound to the same evmChainID. The keys were created with CLI.

Comment: Can you copy paste the error so others who run into it can find this instead of the image? And what does your `.env` look like?

Comment: the `.env` is 
```ROOT=/chainlink
LOG_LEVEL=debug
ETH_CHAIN_ID=4
ALLOW_ORIGINS=*
ETH_URL=wss://eth-rinkeby.xxxxxxxx
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://xxxxxxx@xxxxxx:5432/postgres?sslmode=d$
TLS_CERT_PATH=/chainlink/tls/server.crt
TLS_KEY_PATH=/chainlink/tls/server.key
FEATURE_WEBHOOK_V2=true
CHAINLINK_DEV=true```

Comment: Ah. The multi-chain feature of Chainlink nodes right now is experimental. Right now, I'd stick with 1 chain per node.